# Is this possible to use multiple layouts on the same routes based on the user is authenticated or not?

Tags: angular

Is this possible to use multiple layouts on the same routes based on the user is authenticated or not?

let's suppose I am having two layouts

1. BaseComponent [for logged-in user]
2. NoAuthComponent [for guest user]

Few pages like benefits, terms & conditions and so on pages can be visible to both users (logged-in and guest).

For the demo, I haven't added any routes for both BenefitsComponent and TermsComponent components in the app-routing.module.ts file.

[Here](https://github.com/learn-code-share/multi-layout-angular-app) is the Github link of a sample project
https://github.com/learn-code-share/multi-layout-angular-app

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/github/learn-code-share/multi-layout-angular-app) is the Stackbliz link of sample project running
https://stackblitz.com/github/learn-code-share/multi-layout-angular-app

I did some research but haven't found any useful information.

What I am looking for:

1. Is there a way to achieve this?
2. Is this valid to create such architecture for an application?

Answer (score 0):

You can user `RouteGard` to solve your problem:

```
@Injectable()

export class UserRouteGuard implements CanActivate {

auth: any = {};

constructor(private _authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { }

canActivate() {
 if (_authService.isLoggedIn()) // edit this statement to match your authentication scheme
  { 
        this.router.navigate(['/userRoute']);
        return true;
  }
 else {
        this.router.navigate(['/guestRoute']);
    }    
 }

}
```

you can find more information [here](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate).

Comment: This will help you redirect to another route. I have already added one in the sample project AuthGuard. 
how we can use the same component with different parent layouts is my initial question